# Is it OK to use a biased data set to test predictors that are orthogonal to the bias?

Tags: bias, predictor

I have a data source that manually curates information from news sources. So there are at least two forms of bias: (1) what is covered by the news, and (2) the process of manual curation. So not all events may be included in the data source, and those that are excluded may not be a random subset. I don't have a hard figure for how many events are excluded but believe it to be less than 15%.

The predictor I am looking to test I believe to be uncorrelated with the selection bias. In particular, it relates to weather on the day of the event, which I assume (but cannot prove) is not related to selection for the data source. If I make the assumption of orthogonality between selection bias and the predictor, is it OK to treat the bias as effectively random?

If anyone could point to specific literature, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: It should be fine to analyse your dataset this way, as long as you make clear your assumptions about the unimportance of the biases (as you've done well here).